# Вывод по последнему id

Tags: mysql, php, sql

У меня такой скрипт:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wall WHERE wall='$_GET[id]' LIMIT 0,4") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($wall = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата

?>
<table width='501'>
  <tr>
  <td width='4%'><img src='<?php echo $wall[avatarsender]; ?>' width='60' height='60' style='-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;'></td>
  <td align='left' valign='top'>
    <strong><?php echo $wall[sender]; ?></strong><br />
    <u style='font-size: 13px;'><?php echo $wall[date]; ?></u><br />
    <?php echo $wall[like]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td height='26'>
    <div style='margin: 3px; display: block;'>
    <div style="width: 800px; word-break:break-all">
      <?php echo $wall[entry]; ?>
        <div>
      </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table> <br /><hr></hr><br /><br />
<?php

    }
}

 ?>
```

Мне надо сделать, чтоб из базы выводило по последнему ид, т.е. в базе например 2 строки у 1 строки id1, а у 2 id2, мне надо чтоб при выводе первым отоброжался последний id т.е. 2. Типо такого http://prntscr.com/3d6i0q

Comment: @cnofss, вы слышали о сортировке?

    "SELECT * FROM wall WHERE wall='$_GET[id]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,4"

Comment: Ответ правильный, ответьте на него заново, только не комментарием, а ответом. Я правильный ответ вам поставлю.

Comment: // это защитит вас от sql injection $id = mysql_real_escape_string(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id')); $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wall WHERE wall='$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,4") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());

Comment: Во-первых, это не является ответом на заданный вопрос. Во-вторых, от SQL-инъекций гораздо лучше защищает [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). А про старый API MySQL стоит забыть. И в третьих, чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его и нажмите кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прекрасная функция в PDO - [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

[Пример для mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Ну и можно сделать следующим образом, используя `query`:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_name order by `id` desc limit 1");
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table_name order by `id` desc limit 1") 

//или (PDO #2)

$req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name order by `id` desc limit 1");
$req = $req->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

[ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) может принимать несколько аргументов. Сначала идёт сортировка по первому, потом по второму. В вашем случае будет что-то вроде `SELECT * FROM wall WHERE wall='$_GET[id]' ORDER BY id1, id2 LIMIT 0,4`. Дополнительно можно выставить тип сортировки, например `ORDER BY id1 DESC, id2 DESC`